# Python identity function and itself method

Tags: python

Is there any function in python standard library that returns its argument, something similar to `lambda x: x` and a method that returns its self?

My motivation is to implement something like:

```
def identity(x):
    return x

def default(arg, default, func=identity):
    return func(arg) if arg is not None else func(default)
```

Ruby has `itself` that would be something like:

```
class Self:
    def itself(self):
        return self
```

There are other use cases for a function/method composition that returns its arguments or its self.

Comment: No, there is none, but you seem to have been able to define one easily enough.

Comment: Question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23753569/function-returning-reference-to-itself-python) it seems that it doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

Imho there are two packages that bring `identity` along many other functional, pure python, and performant methods: [funcy](https://funcy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [toolz](https://funcy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)